# Aero arrows using native hacks?

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, aero

Using some P/Invoke, one can create a command link from a button in .NET (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knom/archive/2007/03/12/command_5f00_link.aspx).

I was wondering if a similar procedure was possible for the Previous/Following arrows visible in, for instance, Aero wizards or the Aero Explorer.

[image]

I know I can extract the files myself (and I have already done so), I'm just wondering if there's a more "native" way.

Answer (score -1):

From what I can tell, the [Windows API Code Pack for Microsoft .NET Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) includes the ability to create Task Dialogs, which are the WinVista/Win7 dialogs that have that style of command button and its associated graphics (including the arrows).

The most recent release as of this writing is version 1.1 from August 2010.

Comment: It extracts for half a second, then nothing. Maybe it's just... long. But it looks like what I need.

Comment: P.S.: I actually meant these arrows: http://www.aerotaskforce.com/thumb/back%20button.png/x/560

Comment: It actually does not contain any of the arrows I wanted.